# How to find the index of a class instance in a list from the attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, class, oop

I have a list of all instances of a class. I am tring to find out the index of the instance in that list given an attribute value.

for eg. I have the following code:

```
class Test():
    all_objects=[]
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        Test.all_objects.append(self)

Test("joe",23)
Test("kate",16)
Test("adam",56)

#this is ugly .. 
for ind,item in enumerate(Test.all_objects):
    if item.name == 'joe':
        print(ind)
```

I can find the index of the instance by iterating over each element in the list. **Is there a better way to do this?** (perhaps using the index() method somehow)

**CLARIFICATION:**

I was looking for a way to do this without having to iterate over the `all_objects` list. Looking at the comments and answers below, it seems like there might not be a way around this.

I thank you all for confirming this for me.

Comment: `[obj.name for obj in Test.all_objects].index('joe')`?

Comment: No way to do it without iterating.

Comment: If instance names are supposed to be unique, maybe you want to use a dictionary instead of a list for `all_objects`?

Comment: it is not ugly - it is very readable - and I use only this method as preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using functional programming ⬇

```
my_filter = filter(lambda x: x[1].name == 'joe', enumerate(Test.all_objects))
print(next(my_filter)[0])
```

One liner ⬇

```
print(next(filter(lambda x: x[1].name == 'joe', enumerate(Test.all_objects)))[0])
```

One liner and prints `Not Found` when the specified instance is not found ⬇

```
print(next(filter(lambda x: x[1].name == 'joe', enumerate(Test.all_objects)))[0], 'Not Found')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search many times maybe create a dict with the `name` and its associated object:

```py
objects = {i.name: i for i in Test.all_objects}
```

Now you can access the objects by its name:

```py
a = objects['joe']
```

Obviously that doesn't work if there are multiple objects with the same `name` you can overcome that by using a defaultdict:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

objects = defaultdict(list)
for i in Test.all_objects:
    objects[i.name].append(i)
```

Now every key has a list of objects.